# AWS Glue for user access management & control

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-glue

Recently I've been reading about user access control. I want to cover a scenario like this:
User A & user B both have access to a file.
But user A can only read it, while user B can only write it.
Simply put, I want to give different permissions to my users for my resources.

I want to know whether AWS Glue supports this scenario or not.
Is it an excellent approach to use AWS Glue for this case?
If not, what do you recommend for managing users' access?

Comment: This is done using IAM permissions, and has not much to do with glue.